# Upgrading Artifactory license

Tags: artifactory

We were using Artifactory 3.0.4, whose license got expired. 
We have got the updated license version, but i am not sure how to change the license version. ***Please suggest where to change the licnese version***. 
P.S. Please do not suggest for artifactory migration steps, as our aim is only upgrading the license verion not to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some rigorous search on this question found the solution. Hence posting it for any future help.

```
1.  Login to Artifactory server " su – nexus"
2.  Change the working directory to the artifactory home directory.
    cd Artifactory_3_9_5\etc
3.  Take the backup of the old license files.
    cp artifactory.lic Artifactory_bkp.lic
4.  Also, it is advisable to take the backup of the below files.
    cp artifactory.system.properties artifactory_bkp.system.properties
    cp artifactory.config.bootstrap.xml artifactory_bkp.config.bootstrap.xml  
5.  Either put the new licensed version file to this location or paste the license key to the Artifactory license file(i.e. artifactory.lic).
```